How to allocate a DST struct
I am trying to allocate a DST and I started noticing a problem. The allocate_zeroed function returns a [u8], which is a fat pointer with the size of the whole struct. I am casting it to a fat pointer *mut DST, which reinterprets the fat pointer size to be the data size. This is incorrect; I want the fat pointer size to represent the data size, not the size of the entire DST in bytes.
use std::alloc::{Allocator, Global, Layout};

#[repr(C)]
struct DST {
    other_data: usize,
    other_data2: usize,
    other_data3: usize,
    other_data4: usize,
    data: [u8],
}


unsafe fn create(data_size: usize) {
    let fat_ptr = Global
        .allocate_zeroed(Layout::from_size_align((size_of::<usize>() * 4) + data_size, 8).unwrap())
        .unwrap()
        .as_ptr() as *mut DST;
    assert_eq!((*fat_ptr).data.len(), data_size + size_of::<usize>() * 4); // Pass
    assert_eq!((*fat_ptr).data.len(), data_size); // Failed
}

I want to change the fat pointer size (if that's possible) to data_size. Or make the the fat pointer have the correct size.

Are you sure you want to get into this? Check here for another way: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts

@EugeneSh. Well that is not on the heap and i can't dynamically allocate the DST either

From the docs for Allocator::allocate: "The returned block may have a larger size than specified by layout.size()". That may be what you're running into.

The behaviour you are witnessing is documented in The Rust Reference section on type cast expressions, under Pointer-to-pointer cast (emphasis added):

*const T / *mut T can be cast to *const U / *mut U with the following behavior:
[ deletia ]

If T and U are both unsized, the pointer is also returned unchanged. In particular, the metadata is preserved exactly.
For instance, a cast from *const [T] to *const [U] preserves the number of elements. Note that, as a consequence, such casts do not necessarily preserve the size of the pointer’s referent (e.g., casting *const [u16] to *const [u8] will result in a raw pointer which refers to an object of half the size of the original). The same holds for str and any compound type whose unsized tail is a slice type, such as struct Foo(i32, [u8]) or (u64, Foo).



Instead you must first manually create a pointer with the correct metadata for your struct.
On stable Rust, this can be done using e.g. std::ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut while on nightly Rust with the ptr_metadata feature you can go more directly via std::ptr::NonNull::from_raw_parts_mut.
Note also that your layout calculations are incorrect, as you are ignoring padding (both between the fields and of the resulting struct).
Playground links to working versions: stable and nightly.
